# Persist the data after refreshing the page in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I made a comment application using react
I have three input types (text, link, image) I want them still present the data even after refreshing (reload) the page

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` for this. Have a look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)